# Which defaulted methods are needed in purely abstract base classes?

Tags: c++, abstract-class

As Scott Meyers points out in "Effective Modern C++", no move constructor is generated if a class defines a destructor.

It is not clear to me what that means for abstract base classes, which need to define a (defaulted) virtual destructor.

I do not want the lack of auto-generated methods in my base class to prevent the auto-generation of methods in any derived class.

The focus is only on derived classes, since the abstract base class does not have any data members, so there is no difference between moving and copying the base class. Yet what does it mean for a derived class if its base can only be copied, but not moved?

Which lines in the following class definition are unnecessary?

```
struct AbstractBase {
   AbstractBase () = default;
   AbstractBase (AbstractBase const &) = default;
   AbstractBase (AbstractBase &&) = default;
   AbstractBase & operator = (AbstractBase const &) = default;
   AbstractBase & operator = (AbstractBase &&) = default;
   virtual ~AbstractBase () = default;

   virtual void f () = 0;
};
```

Comment: https://godbolt.org

Comment: @JesperJuhl I guess your link is broken. Do you want to post an actual example or only suggest to use an online compiler?